# Why is my merge sort implementation in Java erring?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am learning Java and algorithms at the same time. I implemented merge sort in this class.

```
public class Sorter {
    private void merge(int [] numbers, int low, int mid, int high) {
            // create a new array that will contain the merged integers
            int[] arrIntMerged = new int[high - low + 1];

            // set indices
            int i = low, j = mid + 1, k = 0;

            // add the lesser integer into merged array
            while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
                if (numbers[i] < numbers[j]) {
                    arrIntMerged[k] = numbers[i];
                    i++;
                } else {
                    arrIntMerged[k] = numbers[j];
                    j++;
                }
                k++;
            }

            // add anything left in the left side of the array
            while (i <= mid) {
                arrIntMerged[k] = numbers[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }

            // add anything left in the right side of the array
            while (j <= high) {
                arrIntMerged[k] = numbers[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }

            // write this newly created array into the positions in the original array
            for (int l = 0; l < arrIntMerged.length; l++) {
                numbers[l + low] = arrIntMerged[l];
            }
        }

        // recursive implementation
        private void _mergeSort(int[] numbers, int low, int high) {
            if (low == high)
                return;
            else {
                // find midpoint while preventing overflow
                int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
                // sort left and right side
                _mergeSort(numbers, low, mid);
                _mergeSort(numbers, mid + 1, high);
                // merge both sides
                merge(numbers, low, mid + 1, high);
            }
        }

        // friendly interface to begin merge sort
        public void mergeSort(int[] numbers) {
            _mergeSort(numbers, 0, numbers.length - 1);
        }
}
```

I then inspected this code in a scrapbook in Eclipse.

```
Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
int[] nums = {5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4};
sorter.mergeSort(nums);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
```

Unfortunately, standard output reads `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]`, which is out of order. Why is my merge sort erring? I am pretty sure of my boundary conditions in `_mergeSort`, so I suspect my `merge` function is awry.

Comment: When you stepped through it with the debugger, what happened?

Comment: You probably have a ++ in a wrong line, because the 1 ends up at the end of the sorted array. However, we are NOT here to debug your code to find that line. Have fun debugging :)

Comment: Hmm ok :) I guess this is a good opportunity for me to learn the debugger. I'll be having fun with http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/debugger.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the following assignment in `merge`:

```
j = mid + 1
```

`mid` is already the index to the first number on the right side of the merge, this increment is making the rest of your merge logic start at the wrong array position.

Because it looks like you are learning, I won't spoil your experience by posting the actual code changes needed, but here a hint: check all the places where you compare things against the `mid` value.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got. Right, mid is already the first index on the right side. Thanks for not debugging it directly :)